How to collect network requests trace of a microservice program and make it run independently with proper mock tools?
I have a microservice program that runs on physical machines, which receives requests from other upstream services on the network and requests data from other downstream services on the network. I want to test the performance of this microservice program individually, so I want to exclude the influence factors of the network and the status of upstream and downstream services.
However, the request types from upstream, the data types returned by downstream, and the network response time all have a significant impact on the program's operation logic, so I cannot directly test it with fabricated random data. Is there a platform or tool that can collect network request information related to the local microservice program during its runtime, and save it as offline files? So that I can use these recorded network requests for mocking in the subsequent independent testing process. (like tracing files commonly used in IO-related experiments, for example, disksim)

Go Replay is my default choice for that. It allows you to capture any traffic and replay it later. Usually, you use it to capture the traffic from production to replay it into other environments.

Thank you for your answer. Go Replay indeed has comprehensive functionality. However, are there any methods to simultaneously record not only the requests received but also the requests sent by the current process to downstream services and their responses as well (and further used as Mock)? Only in this way can I completely separate this process from the microservice network and evaluate it separately.
